# WKWebview not loading images

Tags: ios, image, xamarin, loading, wkwebview

I am opening an url with some images on it in a WKWebview in a Xamarin project. But the images are not loaded. The same URL works in mobile Safari and also worked in UIWebview.

[image: Webpage in WKWebview. No images loaded.]

I already added the domain to NSAppTransportSecurity and set NSAllowsArbitaryLoads to true.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>atlassian.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The result still is, that the images can't be loaded as seen in the safari web information browser in the following screenshot. Also you can see that the missing image are loaded as blob. Other images are loading without a problem.

[image: Network tab of Safari web informations with image url]

Unfortunately I do not have any more information what blocks the image loading.

This is one of the URLs of the page I am trying to display:
https://s3medien.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/WH/pages/33085/PDF+Vorschaubilder+generieren

This is the whole site with more pages:
https://s3medien.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/WH/overview

Maybe someone already had a similar problem and has solved it already. I could't find a solution for this particular problem yet.
Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the url you are using so that I can test on my side?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is one of the urls that don't show images:
https://s3medien.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/WH/pages/33085/PDF+Vorschaubilder+generieren

Comment: Ok, I will test and update you if I find anything.

Comment: Did you find a solution, it looks like wkwebview does not support a blob url?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't find a solution and ended up not using wkwebview but mobile Safari in a popup Window for special cases. Thanks for your effort!